# VueJS Conditional Props and CSS: How to show an svg at the end of a line of text conditionally?

Tags: css, vue.js, svg, sass, vuejs2

I'm trying to handle the addition of an svg through props and a ternary operator, but unlike other stylings I've used, such as has-border, I can't figure out how to get this to work properly.

Getting the svg to show directly at the end of the string and the correct size has proven challenging. As it stands, the svg is taking the padding and margin from the svgs being used above; most likely due to the img tag used.

This maybe a simple CSS question in the end, but I cannot help but feel that the way I've implemented the prop and therefore injection of the svg is incorrect.

All I want is for the text and svg to be together on the same line, in the middle of the cardButton: Like so:

[image]

As you can see below in the code and screenshot I have some conditional props for the image positioning and those css variables may be throwing off external link svg (by adding margin to it).

Have implemented the vue conditional prop correctly and it's just me not getting the css right? and if so, how can I correct this overlap? My fix of
"
.external-link
img
padding: 0
margin: 0
"
Seems to have no effect, but width and height do? (perhaps my utilization of sass is incorrect)

Sorry for the long question. I've tried to simplify the code as much as I could and give only what information is pertinant to the question.

If there is any more information you need to see please let me know!

Vue code

```
<template>
  <div
    :class="[
      hasBorder ? 'has-border' : '',
      imgPosition === 'left' ? 'img-left' : 'img-top',
      isExternalLink ? 'isExternalLink' : '',
    ]"
    class="card-button-wrapper"
  >
    <img :src="imgURL" alt="" />
    <div class="labels">
        {{ label }}<img v-if="isExternalLink" src="external-link.svg" class="external-link" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<style lang="sass" scoped>
.card-button-wrapper
  display: flex
  position: relative
  border-radius: 10px
  width: max-content
  max-width: 630px
  max-height: 340px

.img-left
  width: 630px
  height: 160px
  img
    margin: 24px 40px

.img-top
  flex-direction: column
  align-items: center
  text-align: center
  img
    width: 138px
    height: 138px
    margin-left: 89px
    margin-top: 40px
    margin-right: 72px
    margin-bottom: 50px

.labels
  flex: 1
  display: flex
  justify-content: center
  align-items: left
  flex-direction: column

.has-border
  border: 4px solid navy

.external-link
  img
    padding: 0
    margin: 0
    width: 14px
    height: 14px
</style>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'CardButton',
  props: {
    imgURL: {
      type: String,
    },
    imgPosition: {
      default: 'left',
    },
    hasBorder: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    label: {
      type: String,
    },
    isExternalLink: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
  }
</script>
```

Example.vue (my dev page)

```
<CardButton
      imgURL="/woman-panel-station.svg"
      imgPosition="left"
      :hasBorder="true"
      label="Choices List"
      subLabel="Low Power Simulation/Item Catalogue"
/>
    <br />
 <CardButton label="Company Website" :isExternalLink="true" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't have an `isExternalLink` class. It should be:

```
isExternalLink ? 'external-link' : ''
```

Second, you cannot declare a prop (namely `class`) twice, one value will get overwritten by another. So it should be:

```
  <div
    :class="[
      hasBorder ? 'has-border' : '',
      imgPosition === 'left' ? 'img-left' : 'img-top',
      isExternalLink ? 'external-link' : '',
      'card-button-wrapper'
    ]"
  >
    <img :src="imgURL" alt="" />
    <div class="labels">
        {{ label }}<img v-if="isExternalLink" src="external-link.svg" class="external-link" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

Update:

In a `class` prop, static and dynamic classes can be declared in the same array. For ex.:

```
:class="[
    condition ? 'true-class' : 'false-class',
    'static-class'
]"
```

Concerning the css, from the image you posted, the width is applied correctly 14px x 14px. the displacement of the image is caused by the margins (24px 40px) that are declared in `img-left`. this class is applied by default when you don't define `imgPosition`. You should try setting `margin: 0 !important` in 'external-link' class, for this value to be overwritten.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Yeah, I definitely goofed there with the class. 
On your second point though, I thought you could have a conditional class and a default class (card-button-wrapper); that class is static and not conditional. Is that not the case? 

Final question: Is my implimentation of the classes like .img-left -- img correct? The ones for imgPosition seem to work, but ".external-link -- img" doesn't seem to have any affect (size of svg doesnt change at all).

Cheers again for the response! I really appreciate it

Comment: of course you can have conditional and static classes at the same time. see my updated answer. hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain this all to me! I'm only about 5 months into all of this web dev stuff and this little hick ups can really make me feel like an idiot. You taught me some things I will not forget

Comment: you're welcome. keep up, for 5 months in web dev, you're doing great. cheers!